# Where does the Season 3 TV series start and end in the Manga Chapters?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Where does the season 3 of the TV series of AOT (Part 1) end in the Manga Chapters. What manga chapter is the most recent episode in the TV series?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What chapter does season 3 of Attack on Titan finish at?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49257/what-chapter-does-season-3-of-attack-on-titan-finish-at)

Comment: Partial duplicate but the other half of the question (“where does it begin”) should also have been covered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 of Attack on Titan runs from Vol 13 Chap 51 to Vol 18 Chap 72

Source: [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=47446)